How do you manually install/configure Android Emulator for Maui?
I need to install an Android (API34) for a project I am working on. I can't configure the device through the Android Device Manager as the download always fails with various errors.The Issue I get within VS2022 is
The decryption operation failed, see inner exception. The decryption operation failed, see inner exception. (there is no inner exception that I can see/find)
If I download Android Studio and try that way. I get
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Tag mismatch!.
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom System Image: Tag mismatch!.
I've tried several different internet connections, wifi, mobile and wired, all to no avail.
I can download the images manually but have no idea what to do with them. Any help would be much appreciated.

I would check the system for log files on that error, to get a more detailed error message and may be a stack trace. Alternatively you can try to erase Android Studio and it's user data and reinstall it

Thanks, @Robert I will give that a try. Sadly there are no log files that I could find. I'll try that cleanup and see if it works. I didn't have any error with installing Android Studio, its when I try to download an emulator image, that I come a cropper.

After several hours trying. I had to eventually cobble together a wired connection and that worked. My problem being that my wifi router is quite some distance from my office and my internet in bridged with a long range extender. I got two really long cat 5 cables and two hub/switches to be long enough to get from there to here. I'm guessing my Wifi is a bit glitchy

Do these steps:

Make a new Maui project in Visual Studio
Click on "Android Device Manager"
Select an Android version, and click on “Create”
Check the "Output"; the link of file that will download is there
Download the file manually and put it in the AppData\Local\Temp\xamarin-android-sdk
Come back to Visual Studio and again click on Android Device Manager
Select the Android version that you selected, and it automatically unzip the file

